# Scraping next pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, lxml

I have a code to scrape hotels reviews in python (from yelp).

The code scrape the first page of reviews perfectly, but, I am struggling to scrape the next pages.

The While loop don't work, data scraped in each loop is the same (data of the first page)

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.yelp.com/biz/fairmont-san-francisco-san-francisco?sort_by=rating_desc'
while url:

    r = requests.get(url)
    t = html.fromstring(r.content)
    for i in t.xpath("//div[@class='review-list']/ul/li[position()>1]"):
        rev = i.xpath('.//p[@lang="en"]/text()')[0].strip()
        date = i.xpath('.//span[@class="rating-qualifier"]/text()')[0].strip()
        stars = i.xpath('.//img[@class="offscreen"]/@alt')[0].strip().split(' ')[0]
        print(rev)
        print(date) 
        print(stars) 

    next_page = soup.find('a',{'class':'next'})
    if next_page:
        url = next_page['href']
    else:
        url = None

    sleep(5)
```

here **sleep(5)** before request new url is to avoid limitation set by the website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is one of the ways you can get your job done. I've slightly modified your existing logic of traversing next pages. Give it a shot.

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

url = 'https://www.yelp.com/biz/fairmont-san-francisco-san-francisco?sort_by=rating_desc'

while True:
    res = requests.get(url)
    root = fromstring(res.text)
    for item in root.xpath("//div[@class='review-list']/ul/li[position()>1]"):
        rev = item.xpath('.//p[@lang="en"]/text()')[0].strip()
        print(rev)

    next_page = root.cssselect(".pagination-links a.next")
    if not len(next_page): break
    url = next_page[0].get('href')
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to be smart about looking at the URL. Most websites follow a scheme with their page progression. In this case, it seems like it changes to the following format for the next pages:

```
https://www.yelp.com/biz/fairmont-san-francisco-san-francisco?start=20&sort_by=rating_desc
```

Where the start=20 is where we should be looking. Rewrite the url at the end of the while loop. Once it gets to the end of the page, it should add 20 to that number, and then put it in the string. Like so:

```py
pagenum = 0
while url
    pagenum += 20
    url = "https://www.yelp.com/biz/fairmont-san-francisco-san-francisco?start=" + pagenum + "&sort_by=rating_desc"
```

And then to terminate the program in a try/except catch, where the url wouldn't load because there' no more pages.